# only show if statement in select option

Tags: php, mysql

Why it always show only the condition of single my data is married but it didn`t follow my condition this is my code

```
 $civil = $rowpatient['civil'];
              if ($civil = "Single") {
                 # code...
                ?> <select class='form-control' required name='civil'>
                                     <option>Single</option>
                                     <option>Married</option>
                                     <option>Widowed</option>
                                 </select>
                                 <?php
             }elseif ($civil = "Married") {
                 # code...
               ?> <select class='form-control' required name='civil'>
                                     <option>Married</option>
                                     <option>Widowed</option>
                                     <option>Single</option>
                                 </select> <?php
             }elseif ($civil = "Widowed") {
                 # code...
                ?>
                <select class='form-control' required name='civil'>
                                     <option>Widowed</option>
                                     <option>Married</option>
                                     <option>Single</option>
                                 </select>
                                 <?php
             }
             ?>
```

Comment: Change `$civil =` by `$civil ===`  http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: `=` is for assigning a value not for comparing

Comment: Use `==` or `===` in your conditional statements, not `=` .

Comment: thanks i just forgot that ahahahaha my bad thanks again

Answer (score -2):

The '=' is an assignment operator and will be used to assign values to the variables.

`$a = 10;`

This means store 10 into variable $a;

```
$a = 20;  
$b = $a;
```

The above example means first store 20 into variable $a and then store the variable $a into $b. Since $a is 20 and it is being assigned to $b then automatically $b also becomes 20.

Let's come down to the "==". That's the equality operator. It is used to check whether two values are same.

```
$a = 30;
$b = 30;
if ($a == $b){
    // do something if both are equal
}
```

The comparison uses "==", checking if $a has the same value as of $b. It's not as precise as "===" (also compares the variable *type*), but for most uses, "==" is sufficient.

There are a few other operators also, have a look at the documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: this does two things wrong: 1) answer a to-be-closed question - they should be flagged appropriately, not answered and 2) used a link as your answer

Comment: you also missed out that `==` checks just value and ignores type. So 2 == '2' returns true - still .. the linked dupe covers all of this and this unfortunately doesn't add anything

Comment: Calm your horses @treyBake, I was writing up a full doc.

Comment: sorry i forgot that ahaahhaha it should be equal to not just an equal

Comment: btw thanks for answering my question

Comment: everyone has made that mistake at least once in their life! :-D